# ASP.NET MVC 4 MvcMovie Tutorial Filter query by multiple search criteria

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-4

I was going through the MvcMovie Tutorial and I was trying to modify the SearchIndex() call in the MoviesController to search by multiple criteria. The tutorial shows you how to search by title and genre using the following code:

```
   var movies = from m in db.Movies 
             select m; 

   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString)) 
   { 
       movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString)); 
   } 

   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(movieGenre)) 
       return View(movies); 
   else 
   { 
       return View(movies.Where(x => x.Genre == movieGenre)); 
   }
```

So if I read this right they return all movies then filter on Genre. That would be fine for a dual case but when you add in a 3rd or 4th search criteria you would then increase the amount of if statement calls by a factor of 2 (to the n) - 1 cases. This would get very unruly if for say you had 10 or so columns to search by.

I tried to use something a little more straight forward like:

```
var movieQry = from m in db.Movies
                where ((m.Title !=null && m.Title == searchString) ||
                       (m.Rating != null && m.Rating == movieRating) ||
                       (m.Genre != null && m.Genre == movieGenre))
                select m;
```

but that would not return anything when you first visit the page and only works for a single filter (if I select the Genre - I get good results but not when I select Genre and Rating) and I get nothing returned when I enter a search term for Title.

Is there an easier way to accomplish? (At some point I will need to be able to search on dozens of filters for a project I will be writing... and I have other questions about how to search database for entries but for not this will get me moving in the right direction).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Behnam was kind of on the right track. I modified the code as follows:

```
var movieQry2 = from m in db.Movies
    where ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) ? true : m.Title.Contains(searchString)) &&
           (string.IsNullOrEmpty(movieRating) ? true : m.Rating == movieRating) &&
           (string.IsNullOrEmpty(movieGenre) ? true : m.Genre == movieGenre))
    select m;
```

This works and gives good results. Sorry Behnam can't give you an accepted answer but I did tick it up as being useful. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

if you want to include the column in the criteria if it is not null then try following:

```
  string Title = Request.QueryString["Title"];
  string Rating= Request.QueryString["Rating"];
  string Genre = Request.QueryString["Genre"];

   var movieQry = from m in db.Movies
                    where ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(Title) ? true : m.Title == Title ) &&
                           (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Rating) ? true : m.Rating == Rating ) &&
                           (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Genre)  ? true : m.Genre == Genre ))
                    select m;
```

Comment: This code does not return any of the database entries when there is no search criteria sent in (which should return all database entries) though I may be able to use this in another project where I want to search by specific columns in my database

Comment: if no criteria provided (all are null). then condition would be true && true && true and all records will be returned.

Comment: the columns in the database do contain data but the search criteria sent in is null. On initial visit to page all records are returned. With all search fields empty I get 0 results returned. The url sent in is "/Movies/SearchIndex?movieGenre=&movieRating=&SearchString=" and selecting any combination of search criteria returns 0 records as well

Comment: i think in the first visit all keys are null (but not empty) but in the second one keys are empty.i have updated code.please check.

Comment: well that not what I'm looking for. This code checks to see if the database has entries (which it should for all columns). If I edit that and change whats in the () to the search criteria string (searchString , movieRating, movieGenre) then it partially works. I get good returns from Genre and Rating but as soon as I input a searchString into the text box I receive 0 results.

Comment: oh... what a mistake i have made.we must compare with keywords not values itself.i have updated code.

Comment: @jbolt i have updated code for last time (i promise).check it :D.

Comment: No sorry that doesn't return correct results. It returns All results every time regardless of what search criteria is selected. This seems to be checking if the database entries are null in which case this might work for that situation. Using a combinations of your code with my own I have gotten a viable solution. See my next post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var movieQry = db.Movies
  .Where(x=> (Title == null || x.Title ==Title)
   && (Rating == null || x.Rating == Rating)
   && (Genre == null || x.Genre == Genre))                       
 .ToList();
```

For other paging and sorting see [MVC multiple field search](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1141/mvc-multiple-field-search-with-webgrid-step-5)